# Add an Apache POI WorkBook as attachment to a Javamail's MimeMessage without writing in the filesystem

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-poi

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a `WorkBook` (from the Apache POI library) "directly" to a `MimeMessage` object (from the Javamail library) as an attachment, without having to write it directly in the filesystem.

The simplest way to do this seems the following:

```
File attachmentSource = new File("tmpsource.xls");

WorkBook tmpWorkbook = new HSSFWorkBook();
//Do stuff with workbook
tmpWorkBook.write(new FileOutputStream(attachmentSource));

//Create all the Session, MimeMessage and MimeMultipart
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(attachmentSource)));
attachment.setFileName(attachmentSource.getName());

//Do stuff with the message and send it
```

This way it works but I'm forced to write down the file into the FS.

While reading the related questions I found out about `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` and seemed to solve my problem (Unless the file swells up to `2GB` which seems very unlikely).

I hope I explained myself, I think the ByteArray streams will do the trick, by the way any help or advice are appreciated!

**[09/29/2011]**
I created a very simple `DataSource` implementation called (guess what) `ByteArrayDataSource`, so I have the automatic headers setup and Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 4):

One of the `MimeBodyPart` constructors takes a byte array (the content of the attachment) as argument. So just write your workbook to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, transform this stream to a byte array, and pass this byte array to the constructor:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
tmpWorkBook.write(baos);
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart(internetHeaders, baos.toByteArray());
// or MimeBodyPart attachment = 
//        new MimeBodyPart(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: Ok, I really hoped that this way worked but the binary data is written straight into the mail body, so no cool automatic headers set up and no cool base64 encoding. :( Am I missing something?